# Trying to make an array of hashmap keys from an array of hashmap values returning null

Tags: java, loops, sorting, hashmap, bubble-sort

I have created a method which takes in a hashmap as input, converts the values into an array, sorts the array using bubble sort and then I want it to use the sorted values to select the first N index keys from the initial hashmap. I understand this is not the best way to do this but that is fine (I have written this method as an alternative).

The method returns null since maxItems is empty and the "System.out.println(entry.getKey());" doesn't print anything to the console.

Thanks for any help!

public String[] getMaxListAlt(int n, HashMap<String, Integer> itemCount) {

```
    itemCount.values().toArray();

    Integer[] maxArray = itemCount.values().toArray(new Integer[0]);

    int length = maxArray.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length-1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < length-i-1; j++)
            if (maxArray[j] > maxArray[j+1])
            {
                int temp = maxArray[j];
                maxArray[j] = maxArray[j+1];
                maxArray[j+1] = temp;
                
            }

    String[] maxItems = new String[n];
    int maxIndex = n-1;
    System.out.println(maxIndex);


    for (int i=0; i >= n-1; i++) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : itemCount.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().equals(maxArray[i])) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey());
                maxItems[i] = entry.getKey();
            }
        }
    }

        for (int counts : maxArray) {

        System.out.println(counts);

    }

    return maxItems;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for`-loop doesn't run because you've got a typo - `int i=0; i>= n-1;` but your `i` can never be larger than your `n-1`. Instead:

```
for (int i=0; i <= n-1; i++) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : itemCount.entrySet()) {
```

Comment: Jack Goodwin consider accepting an answer

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do, here is another approach that you may be interested in.  However, it seems that you may be doing a couple things incorrectly.

1. Your bubble sort is sorting in ascending order which I didn't think you wanted.
2. When looping thru the `entrySet` you are getting repeated values since you always come to the first one with a certain number.  But it may be a repeat of what you already have.

The following streaming process works like this.

- First it streams the arrays of strings
- Then creates a mapped based frequency count using `groupingBy`
- Then it streams the `entryset` and sorts in descending order based on the values (the count)
- then it limits the number of entries to `n` and maps the keys to the stream
- and returns those keys in the array.

Create some test data

```
Random r = new Random();
String[] v = r.ints(100, 'a', 'z' + 1)
        .mapToObj(c -> (char) c + "").toArray(String[]::new);

int n = 10;
```

The streaming process

```
Map<String, Long> itemCount = Arrays.stream(v)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a, Collectors.counting()));
        
String[] result = itemCount.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Entry.<String,Long>comparingByValue().reversed())
        .limit(n).map(Entry::getKey).toArray(String[]::new);

for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(result[i] + " --> " + itemCount.get(result[i]));
}
```

Prints something like

```
h --> 7
q --> 7
t --> 7
f --> 6
a --> 5
e --> 5
m --> 5
x --> 5
z --> 5
d --> 4
```

Note the first stream, if desired, could flow right into the second by streaming the `entrySet()`.  In that case you return the array and never see the actual map.

**If you want to keep your original map**

Here is a modification with comments if you want to use your original map and method.

```
public static String[] getMaxListAlt(int n,
        Map<String, Long> itemCount) {
    
    
    // copy entries to a list for sorting.
    List<Entry<String,Long>> entries = new ArrayList<>(itemCount.entrySet());
    
    // sort the entries based on value in  reverse order.
    entries.sort(Entry.<String,Long>comparingByValue().reversed());
    
    // now create the array and just grab the top n items from the sorted
    // entries list.
    String[] maxItems = new String[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        maxItems[i] = entries.get(i).getKey();
    }
    
    return maxItems;
}
```